# Multithreading to draw multiple bounding boxes on a common figure (fig,ax) with maltplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, matplotlib, multiprocessing

Currently, I am using for loop to go through each bounding box to draw it and fill it with corresponding text. Since it is taking quite some time with 'for' loop, I am thinking of using multithreading/ multiprocessing to simultaneously draw those on the same figure. Do you think it's possible and if so, can you also give me an example?